# SQL - Get data between two dates grouped by week

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

This question might have been solved many times or even asked many times. But as I am not a savvy in SQL, I am not able to figure out things found on the internet. Like I am not able to tweak Queries from the Internet to my needs. 
And here comes my need

I have a Table named **`Orders`** Containing Fields like `OrderId`, `OrderDate` etc.

I need to generate an Excel Sheet. The sheet will have the count of orders grouped by week. 
(Like how many orders placed within that week)

The user can choose the year in which he/she needs the report for.

So if the user chooses the current year then I need to generate an excel report containing data from Jan 1 to today grouped by week.

If the user chooses any other year(maybe previous years) then I need to generate a report containing all the data for that year grouped by week.

**Currently, I am looking for an SQL query that returns data like this(expected output)**

```
Week    Date Range               Total No of Orders
-----+--------------------------+-------------------
week#1  2018-01-01 - 2018-01-07     10 
week#2  2018-01-08 - 2018-01-14     0
week#3  2018-01-15 - 2018-01-21     1
```

How can I write a query to achieve the same?

Looking for expert advice...

Comment: Edit the question add some sample data and desire result would helpful.

Comment: @YogeshSharma hello, sample data in the sense ??? my table Orders have OrderId(int type) , OrderDate(Datetime) and few other fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use **CTE recursive** write calendar by week number,then `Orders` `LEFT JOIN` on CTE calendar table get `COUNT`.

Note:

- variable `@Dt` mock which year you want to start.

Query look like this.

```
DECLARE @Dt date = '2018-01-01' 

;WITH CTE(Dt,maxD) AS (
  SELECT DATEPART(ww,@Dt) Dt, DATEPART(ww,MAX(OrderDate)) maxD
  FROM Orders
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT (Dt +1) Dt,maxD
  FROM CTE
  WHERE (Dt +1) <= maxD
)
SELECT CONCAT('week#',c.Dt) 'week',
       CONCAT(
         CONVERT(char(10),dateadd(week,c.Dt-1, DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,-1,DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy,0,getdate()), 0)), 0)),126)
         ,'-'
         , CONVERT(char(10),dateadd(week,c.Dt, DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,-1,DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy,0,getdate()), 0)), 0)),126)) 'Date Range',
       COUNT(o.OrderDate) 'Total No of Orders'
FROM CTE c 
LEFT JOIN Orders o on c.Dt = DATEPART(ww,o.OrderDate)
GROUP BY c.Dt
```

*sqlfiddle:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/8f089/40*

Comment: That was quick and what I have asked for... you are awesome man.

Comment: I have a doubt. this query works awesome if it is 2018. like if I pass 2018-01-01 and 2018-12-31 as the dates, but when I tried the same with 2016 my first week started with this date 2015-12-28. is it possible to start from the first day of that year ?